# Does using a 'SortExpression' in a BoundField in a DetailsView make any sense?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, detailsview

I'm studying for a M$ certificate. I use the 'self-paced' Training Kit (book). I bumped into something which confuses me a bit. After finding some code samples online doing the same, I decided to ask the community.

This is the text:

> The DetailsView control does not directly support sorting, whereas the GridView control
>   does. However, you can use the DataSource control, as discussed in Lesson 1, to manage data
>   sorting.

And here is a snip from the sample code in the book:

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server" Width="300px"
ID="DetailsView1"
AllowPaging="True"
AutoGenerateRows="False"
DataKeyNames="ProductID"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Fields>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID"
        InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName"
        SortExpression="ProductName" />
    ...
    ...
    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True"
        ShowInsertButton="True" />
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

The question is: Does this SortExpression have any point here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GridView and DetailsView uses the BoundField, CommandField, etc. so this is useful for the GridView, but not for the DetailsView.  DetailsView is singular in form as it only shows one record at a time so sorting wouldn't be beneficial to expose.

HTH.

Comment: "wouldn't be beneficial"? That sounds like it actually would do something when specifying it. Or did you mean "doesn't make any sense"?

Comment: It would be very easy to test.  In the example above do you have a click-able header?  If yes, does it cause a post-back?  Like Brian said those template fields are shared in many different controls, therefor you have properties that might or might not make sense 100% in every application.

Comment: @TweeZz Wouldn't be beneficial = they didn't implement it :-)

Comment: @e36M3 A DetailsView doesn't have anything like a clickable header.. let alone a header :) I know they are shared, but just the fact that they specified it in a DetailsView is what confused me.
My suspicions where confirmed :) thx!

Comment: The world of copy/paste, we're all guilt of it to some degree :)  Most likely why you see it in some examples.